# How and where do I fix this math error? Cart totals are being added/subtracted wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, shipping, tax

Thank you in advance for any help.

I am not sure when this happened. It seems to only be for our home state as that is the only place we charge tax. In the cart it adds the shipping for the **Grand Total Incl.** Tax then it subtracts the tax for the **Grand Total Excl. Tax**.
[image]
204.48+20.00=224.48 (bottom number)
224.48-13.47=211.01 (middle number)

In the checkout it does display the correct amount as seen here.
[image]

But when the order comes to us and what it shows in the back end have it backwards like the cart. What the heck am I missing and where can I fix this? Thank you for any help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. It appears to have been a PHP 7 sort order error.
With the help of [/u/salubrium](https://www.reddit.com/user/salubrium) and [/u/keteb](https://www.reddit.com/user/keteb) on the Magento subreddit we got it working.

I tested the site by switch the PHP version to 5.6 and the site worked fine.
So using the suggestion they gave me I installed [Inchoo_PHP7](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/tree/1.9.2.4) ,which looks to be a backwards compatibly addon for Magento. I then set the site back PHP 7 and the site worked as it should.